# Issue mouseenter mouse leave on iPad/iPhone

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I am developing this [website](http://heidenweid.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/testing/) using **Wordpress** and as you can see there is a table of content.

For each row I setted a `mouseenter mouseleave` jQuery script that toggle different images on top of the table.

This works on desktop (and on Android devices) but does not works on iPad/iPhone.

Any ideas on how can I solve it?

This is a part of the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-2", function () {
        $('.A_E_1').toggle();
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-3", function () {
        $('.A_E_2').toggle();
    });

});
```

What i tried without results:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(document.body).on("touchstart touchend", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-2", function () {
        $('.A_E_1').toggle();
    });

    $(document.body).on("touchstart touchend", ".tablepress-id-1 .row-3", function () {
        $('.A_E_2').toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: "What i tried without results...". There's always results. What didn't that code do that you expected it to? Did it act exactly the same as the first example?

Comment: @Carcigenicate with the second code happen that on touch start I can see the animation but on touchend the animation stops.